# Kubernetes stuck on "ContainerCreating" while using quota

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to use the quota feature in kubernetes but everytime my container is stuck on "ContainerCreating" and not moving forward.

I'm not sure what could be the issue .

MyQuota yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: awesome-quota
spec: 
  hard:
     pods: 2
     requests.cpu: 1
     requests.memory: 1024m
     limits.cpu: 4
     limits.memory: 4096m

status: {}
```

My nginx yaml having quota details:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.18.0
    name: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: "1024m"
      requests:
        cpu: "0.5"
        memory: "512m"
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Thanks
Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the memory unit to "Mi". Note your sample was modified slightly to limit the scope in kube-public namespace.

```
> cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ResourceQuota
> metadata:
>   name: test-quota
>   namespace: kube-public
> spec: 
>   hard:
>      pods: 2
>      requests.cpu: 1
>      requests.memory: 1024Mi
>      limits.cpu: 4
>      limits.memory: 4096Mi
> EOF
resourcequota/test-quota created
```

Run your sample pod:

```
> cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   labels:
>     app: nginx
>   name: nginx
>   namespace: kube-public
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - image: nginx:latest
>     name: nginx
>     resources:
>       limits:
>         cpu: "1"
>         memory: "1024Mi"
>       requests:
>         cpu: "0.5"
>         memory: "512Mi"
>   dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
>   restartPolicy: Never
> EOF
pod/nginx created
```

The pod runs as expected:

```
> kubectl get pods -n kube-public
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx   1/1     Running   0          37s
```

If resources.limits has no upper bound:

```
> cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   labels:
>     app: nginx
>   name: nginx
>   namespace: kube-public
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - image: nginx:latest
>     name: nginx
>     resources:
>       requests:
>         cpu: "0.5"
>         memory: "512Mi"
>   dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
>   restartPolicy: Never
> EOF
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "STDIN": pods "nginx" is forbidden: failed quota: test-quota: must specify limits.cpu,limits.memory
```

Comment: Thanks , can you explain why its not working for " requests.memory: 1024m" , is that "m" in the end signify something else for which k8 is not able to allocate enough memory but still in that case it should report it as an error.

Comment: If you use 'M' it will work. Why is that has a lot to do with the underlying container runtime that processed the request. 'Mi' is known to be the most consistent across all.

Comment: According to the official documentation from [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-memory):
Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. You can express memory as a plain integer or as a fixed-point number using one of these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, k. You can also use the power-of-two equivalents: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki.